# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'and')

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

Please help! I get the type error up above when trying to run a shallow integration test.

I have severally looked through my code to check if I have something amiss, but everything seems to be in place.

I'm trying to get this test to pass.

```
expect(fixture.componentInstance.heroes.length).toBe(3)
```

It keeps failing with this error in Karma.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'and')

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing"
import { of } from "rxjs";
import { HeroService } from "../hero.service";
import { HeroesComponent } from "./heroes.component"

describe('HeroesComponent (shallow tests)', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeroesComponent>;
  let mockHeroService;
  let HEROES;  

  beforeEach(() =>{
    HEROES = [
      {id:1, name: 'SpiderDude', strength: 8},
      {id:2, name: 'Wonderful Woman', strength: 24},
      {id:3, name: 'SuperDude', strength: 55}
    ];
    mockHeroService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getHeroes, addHero, deleteHero']);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HeroesComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: HeroService, useValue: mockHeroService}
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeroesComponent)
  })

  it('should set heroes correctly from the service', () => {
    mockHeroService.getHeroes.and.returnValue(of(HEROES))
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(fixture.componentInstance.heroes.length).toBe(3)
  });
});
```

Comment: You have not mocked your hero service properly.

Comment: You were right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotes in the mockHeroService methods are not placed correctly.

```
mockHeroService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getHeroes, addHero, deleteHero']);
```

It should be this instead.

```
mockHeroService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getHeroes', 'addHero', 'deleteHero']);
```

Comment: Or even better, use the awsome [auto-spies](https://github.com/hirezio/auto-spies) library: `import { createSpyFromClass } from 'jasmine-auto-spies'; ... mockHeroService = createSpyFromClass(HeroService)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what Unit test framework you are using:

Your line here

```
 mockHeroService.getHeroes.and.returnValue(of(HEROES))
```

By the the error, I can tell that the compiler are trying to read property `and` from object `mockHeroService.getHeroes`. But the `mockHeroService.getHeroes` itself is undefined. So the compiler can not read `and` of undefined

The problem is here `mockHeroService.getHeroes`

Please check the `mockHeroService` with jasmine

Comment: I don't think this is true, if node throws:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'and')
It means that it's the and itself that's undefined. It's not that it's a function instead of a member.

Comment: This is all I've written so far in terms of this test. You can see me setting up the mockHeroService when I wrote this line  mockHeroService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getHeroes, addHero, deleteHero']);.

Comment: You were right! The quotes in the mockHeroService methods are wrong.